# Powershell Count context switches

Tags: powershell, context-switch

I'm trying to display the number of context switches during one second in PowerShell. I've so far been trying the `Get-Counter -Counter "System\Context Switches/sec"` with both " " and  ' ' and both leads to the error:

```
Get-Counter : Internal performance counter API call failed. Error: c0bc4
```

I'm aware of the perfmon's ability to show this, I need it displayed as text in Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geeze, I just realized these commands are language-specific. My norwegian system only accepts norwegian commands. So that solves my problem!

Norwegian command: `Get-Counter -Counter "\System\Kontekstvekslinger/sek"`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a leading `\`. This will work:

```
get-counter -Counter "\System\Context Switches/sec"
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried this aswell, leading to same error-code. *edit* Almost same code -> c0bb9.

Comment: Works fine for me. When I use the one in your question I get the same error code. Tried in all versions of powershell too and it works in each. Did you try running as administrator?

Comment: Yes I've also ran it as administrator with same result, weird!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the computer name in the path.

```
get-counter -Counter "\\<computer-name>\System\Context Switches/sec"
```

Although the archo444 answer should work.

Comment: I've tested this aswell, with same result :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
$All = Get-Counter -ListSet * | ForEach-Object -Process { $PSItem.Paths; $PSItem.PathsWithInstances; }

get-counter -Counter ($All | Select-String -Pattern "context" )
```

i get same error like you i try like this and get result fine